# How to get push notification in salesforce1 when a record is created?

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

We want a mobile push up notification when a record is created in custom objects  ?
Is it possible ?

If yes, how can we do that ?

I have checked

[Push notification in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138601/push-notification-in-salesforce1)

But this answer for mobile SDK. We need it into salesforce1 mobile app.

I want to know it is possible or not.

Comment: Have you taken a look at these links -- [Activate Salesforce for Android and iOS Push Notifications](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194290&type=1) & [Enable Salesforce App Notifications](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notifications_enable.htm&type=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you yourself provided has the answer you need, although you'll have to dig through some of the links in that post as well as checking out Jayant's comment.

### Chatter

The default push notification features are set up to work off of chatter.

[With a little rigging you could add a trigger that automatically @mentions the record owner in the chatter feed which could shoot off a push notification.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm)

### From documentation

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

mentionSegmentInput.id = '005RR000000Dme9';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

textSegmentInput.text = 'Could you take a look?';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = '0F9RR0000004CPw';

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput, null);
```

[More chatter apex examples.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples.htm)

### Approval Process

You could also create an approval process for the record. This will send a push notification to the approver when it's their turn to review the record.

> Note: Push notifications for approval tasks are controlled by the "Receive Approval Request Emails" User profile setting.

This could provide a code free approach but does require the user take action on the record which makes it a bit more than just a notification.